# Mysql 5.1 Improve Performance for InnoDB

Tags: mysql, debian, innodb

I have a server on Debian 6 using Mysql 5.1 and I'm having problems with big tables on Innodb. As Mysql was installed on its default configurations I'd like to know some suggestion about how to improve the performance of my server.

DB **Mysql 5.1**
Operative System: Debian6

I have 4G available on free memory according free -g command on Debian.
I have 6GB on swap on Debian OS.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 8388608    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 2097152000 |
| innodb_log_buffer_size  | 1048576    |
| join_buffer_size        | 131072     |
| key_buffer_size         | 16777216   |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size | 8388608    |
| net_buffer_length       | 16384      |
| preload_buffer_size     | 32768      |
| read_buffer_size        | 131072     |
| read_rnd_buffer_size    | 262144     |
| sort_buffer_size        | 2097144    |
| sql_buffer_result       | OFF        |
+-------------------------+------------+
12 rows in set
```

I have to mention that the only thing I have changed on my cnf file is innodb_buffer_pool_size to 2097152000 but I have no get good result about performance.
By the way on my server I have big tables with partitions and big tables on MyIsam as well.

Comment: How do you know your performance issues are down to your innodb configuration?  Whilst it's true that the default settings are not optimal, I would suggest a careful examination of the queries you're running is also in order.

Comment: How "big"?  How many partitions?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%open%';`

Comment: If you're using default configuration, then you may not be aware that 5.1 has two different versions of InnoDB shipped with it.  Take sufficient time and read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/

Comment: My queries are ok, and at the moment I have 2 tables partitioned by month from 2012 until now. I just dont know if partition table with innodb engine makes a lock on partition, that's something i read from Giuseppe Maxia for mysql 5.1. But on sunday i went to test this and my server behaves really good, so not see the problem. About queries they are optimized by indexs

Comment: Rick, I only have 2 tables partitioned and both are on innodb engine and data from 2012 until now, the partition was made by month. I need to know if do i need to set up something else to get a good performance on my server because there are some times when my server goes down and i have noticed that it is when they insert on a partitioned table. Inmediatly i went to Giuseppe Maxia's froum [http://datacharmer.blogspot.pe/2010/05/two-quick-performance-tips-with-mysql.html] .
RIck according what I got from "show variables like 'buffer%'" do you see anything else I should optimize?